# If discriminant of f is a perfect square, then we can factor f into linear factors

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Let $f$ be a binary quadratic form with integer coeficients, $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. I'm trying to prove that if $d=b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square $d=k^2$, then we can factor $f(x,y)=(a_1x+a_2y)(a_3x+a_4y)$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I tried various manipulations, and I find something that is almost what I want, mainly $4af(x,y)=(2axy+by)^2-dy^2=(2axy+by-ky)(2axy+by+ky)$, but I didn't get much further...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $z = \frac xy$.  We can write
$$
f(x,y) = y^2(az^2 + bz + c)
$$
Using the quadratic formula, how can we factor $az^2 + bz + c$, assuming the discriminant is a perfect square?

Comment: $az^2+bz+c=a(z-\frac{-b+k}{2a})(z-\frac{-b-k}{2a})$ but how can I guarantee that the coeficients are integers?

Comment: For that, you need [Gauss's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial))

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how Gauss's Lemma can help here. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: Not a problem. Gauss's lemma states that if an integer polynomial cannot be factored over the integers, it cannot be factored over the rationals.  Equivalently, if it can be factored over the rationals, it can be factored over the integers.  Thus, once you have a factorization where the coefficients are rational, you can guarantee by Gauss's lemma that there is a factorization with integer coefficients.

Comment: I apologize for maybe not seeing something completely trivial, but how can I factor $(x+\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{2}{3})$ over the integers?

Comment: You can't, because that is not a factorization of an integer polynomial.  You can, however, factor $6(x + \frac 12)(x + \frac 23)$ over the integers.

Comment: Oh, sorry, absolutely. Thank you for your help!